# Seq2Seq implementation with different latent dimensions for Encoder and Decoder

Tags: python, keras, seq2seq

Most of the sample implementations (especially with Keras) has same latent dim both for encoder and decoder, and I guess the reason for that is to share the state of encoder with decoder.
I'm looking for the sample implementation of Seq2Seq whose encoder and decoder have different latent dimensions.
Do you guys know some?

Comment: Have you considered how would that work conceptually? It would make no mathematical sense.

Comment: So you should design the parameters of the encoder and the decoder to meet the same dimensions.